# How to reply to an snmp request with an SNMP agent?

Tags: snmp

So my question is how does an SNMP agent retrieve the information after it has decoded the oid?

For example a simple snmp request would be snmp-get the oid being sent would be 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 which would translate to "so.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysDescr" , this would be a request for the full name and version identification of the system's hardware type, software operating-system, and networking software.

After knowing what it requires how does the SNMP agent compose a response ? Does it query something else? If it does query the system how does it query it ..

Comment: I can call myself one of the SNMP agent vendors, https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/samples/agent-development.html But if you understand C# and the code base, you can see that the "translate to" part is never necessary. I can simply map each OID to some piece of code directly. About what value might be returned, every vendors has their freedom, and you can get different values (for sysDescr) if different agents are used. So to make your question answerable, you would have to focus on a single agent, or all.

Comment: So basically are you saying that u just map all OID's to a separate pieces of code that then retrieve information from the PC ? My question was a little vague so sorry, but i was mainly looking at the retrieval of said information via the agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to read and understand the standard [RFC 3411](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3411#section-3.1.3.2) titled

```
                 An Architecture for Describing
Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Management Frameworks
```

in particular section 3.1.3.2 "SNMP Agent" which shows the architecture of the agent. You are asking about the box "MIB instrumentation", which is further detailed down in section 3.3 .

That standard is then implemented differently in each SNMP framework, usually via callbacks for each of the registered MIB objects. You compile the MIB that you want to handle in the agent, and it generates the stubs for the callbacks, which you then fill out to retrieve the information for each object and return it in the desired format.